# How to output one data stream to different outputs depending on the data?

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

In Apache Flink I have a stream of tuples. Let's assume a really simple `Tuple1<String>`. The tuple can have an arbitrary value in it's value field (e.g. 'P1', 'P2', etc.). The set of possible values is finite but I don't know the full set beforehand (so there could be a 'P362'). I want to write that tuple to a certain output location depending on the value inside of the tuple. So e.g. I would like to have the following file structure:

- `/output/P1`
- `/output/P2`

In the documentation I only found possibilities to write to locations that I know beforehand (e.g. `stream.writeCsv("/output/somewhere")`), but no way of letting the contents of the data decide where the data is actually ending up.

I read about output splitting in the documentation but this doesn't seem to provide a way to redirect the output to different destinations the way I would like to have it (or I just don't understand how this would work).

Can this be done with the Flink API, if so, how? If not, is there maybe a third party library that can do it or would I have to build such a thing on my own?

Comment: please don't add a solution in the answer. You can post a self-answer below instead if the answer hasn't already been proposed

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can implement a custom sink. Inherit from one of both:

- `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.SinkFunction`
- `org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.sink.RichSinkFunction`

In your program use:

```
stream.addSink(SinkFunction<T> sinkFunction);
```

instead of `stream.writeCsv("/output/somewhere")`.

Comment: Thank you! I checked the implementation of `FileSinkFunction` and came up with something similar on my own. I added the implementation to my question for reference.